# creating procedural generated RPG Dungeon maps

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, role-playing-game

## Intro

I am building a rogue like RPG, currently it is still a work in progress, but I would like to get an intermediate review of my Procedural map generation code.

I've chosen to use the Binary Space Partitioning algo, because it would make my life easier in the future when I will add corridors to the rooms.

There are some TODO's left,

- Creating random rooms within the leaves
- Adding corridors to connect the (random-sized) rooms

but they are not up for review.

## Code

```
from queue import Queue
from random import choice, randint
from collections import namedtuple
from enum import Enum

Position = namedtuple("Position", ["y", "x"])

class Tile(Enum):
    WALL = '#'
    EMPTY = ' '
    ROCK = '.'

class Split(Enum):
    HORIZONTAL = 0
    VERTICAL   = 1

class Room():
    def __init__(self, lu, rd):
        self.lu = lu
        self.rd = rd

    @property
    def position_map(self):
        return self._get_positions()

    @property
    def border_map(self):
        return self._get_border()

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self.rd.x - self.lu.x

    @property
    def height(self):
        return self.rd.y - self.lu.y

    def _get_positions(self):
        return [
            Position(row, col)
            for col in range(self.lu.x + 1, self.rd.x) 
            for row in range(self.lu.y + 1, self.rd.y)
        ]

    def _get_border(self):
        return [Position(y, self.lu.x) for y in range(self.lu.y, self.rd.y)] + \
               [Position(y, self.rd.x) for y in range(self.lu.y, self.rd.y)] + \
               [Position(self.lu.y, x) for x in range(self.lu.x, self.rd.x)] + \
               [Position(self.rd.y, x) for x in range(self.lu.x, self.rd.x + 1)]

class Leaf():
    def __init__(self, lu, rd, parent, min_room_space):
        self.lu = lu
        self.rd = rd
        self.parent = parent
        self.min_room_space = min_room_space
        self._children = None
        self._sibling = None
        self._room = None

    @property
    def children(self):
        return self._children

    @children.setter
    def children(self, value):
        self._children = value

    @property
    def sibling(self):
        return self._sibling

    @sibling.setter
    def sibling(self, value):
        self._sibling = value

    @property
    def room(self):
        return self._room or self._generate_room()

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self.rd.x - self.lu.x

    @property
    def height(self):
        return self.rd.y - self.lu.y

    def _generate_room(self):
        #TODO create random sized room in the leaf
        room = Room(self.lu, self.rd)
        self._room = room
        return room

class Map():
    def __init__(self, width, height, min_room_space=10, split_threshold=1.25):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.lu = Position(0, 0)
        self.rd = Position(height-1, width-1)
        self.min_room_space = min_room_space
        self.split_threshold = split_threshold
        self._leaves = None
        self.board = [[Tile.ROCK.value] * (self.width) for _ in range(self.height)]

    @property
    def leaves(self):
        return self._leaves

    def generate(self):
        # Reset the board
        self.board = [[Tile.ROCK.value] * (self.width) for _ in range(self.height)]
        self._generate_leaves()
        for leaf in self.leaves:
            for pos in leaf.room.position_map:
                self.board[pos.y][pos.x] = Tile.EMPTY.value
            for pos in leaf.room.border_map:
                self.board[pos.y][pos.x] = Tile.WALL.value

        #TODO Create corridors by adding corridors from the children up to the highest in the tree

    def _generate_leaves(self):
        splitable = Queue()
        splitable.put(Leaf(self.lu, self.rd, None, self.min_room_space))
        leaves = Queue()
        while splitable.qsize() > 0:
            leaf = splitable.get()
            leaf_a, leaf_b = self._split(leaf)

            if leaf_a is None and leaf_b is None:
                leaves.put(leaf)
            else:
                leaf.children = (leaf_a, leaf_b)
                leaf_a.sibling = leaf_b
                leaf_b.sibling = leaf_a
                splitable.put(leaf_a)
                splitable.put(leaf_b)

        self._leaves = list(leaves.queue)

    def _split(self, leaf):
        if leaf.width / leaf.height >= self.split_threshold:
            return self._split_room(leaf, Split.HORIZONTAL)
        elif leaf.height / leaf.width >= self.split_threshold:
            return self._split_room(leaf, Split.VERTICAL)
        else:
            return self._split_room(leaf, choice([Split.VERTICAL, Split.HORIZONTAL]))

    def _split_room(self, leaf, direction):
        leaf_a = leaf_b = None
        if direction == Split.VERTICAL:
            if not leaf.height < self.min_room_space * 2:
                random_split = randint(leaf.lu.y + self.min_room_space, leaf.rd.y - self.min_room_space)
                leaf_a = Leaf(leaf.lu,
                              Position(random_split, leaf.rd.x),
                              leaf,
                              self.min_room_space)
                leaf_b = Leaf(Position(random_split + 1, leaf.lu.x),
                              leaf.rd,
                              leaf,
                              self.min_room_space)
        elif direction == Split.HORIZONTAL:
            if not leaf.width < self.min_room_space * 2:
                random_split = randint(leaf.lu.x + self.min_room_space, leaf.rd.x - self.min_room_space)
                leaf_a = Leaf(leaf.lu,
                              Position(leaf.rd.y, random_split),
                              leaf,
                              self.min_room_space)
                leaf_b = Leaf(Position(leaf.lu.y, random_split + 1),
                              leaf.rd,
                              leaf,
                              self.min_room_space)
        return leaf_a, leaf_b

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join("".join(b) for b in self.board)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = Map(50, 50, 10)
    m.generate()
    print(m)
```

## Example Output

```
##################################################
#              ##        ##           ##         #
#              ##        ##           ##         #
#              ##        ##           ##         #
#              ##        ##           ##         #
#              ##        ##           ##         #
#              ##        ##           ##         #
#              ##        ##           ##         #
#              ##        ##           ##         #
#              ##        ##           ##         #
#              ##        ##           ##         #
#              ##        ##           ##         #
#              ##        ##           ############
#              ##        ##           ############
#              ##        ##           ##         #
#              ##        ##           ##         #
########################################         #
########################################         #
#          ##         ##              ##         #
#          ##         ##              ##         #
#          ##         ##              ##         #
#          ##         ##              ##         #
#          ##         ##              ##         #
#          ##         ##              ##         #
#          ##         ##              ##         #
#          ##         ##              ##         #
#          ##         ##              ##         #
#          ##         ##              ##         #
#          ##         ##              ##         #
#          ##         ##              ##         #
#          ##         ##              ##         #
#          ##         ##              ############
#          ##         ##              ############
#          ##         ##              ##         #
#          ##         ##              ##         #
########################################         #
########################################         #
#           ##              ##        ##         #
#           ##              ##        ##         #
#           ##              ##        ##         #
#           ##              ##        ##         #
#           ##              ##        ##         #
#           ##              ##        ##         #
#           ##              ##        ##         #
#           ##              ##        ##         #
#           ##              ##        ##         #
#           ##              ##        ##         #
#           ##              ##        ##         #
#           ##              ##        ##         #
##################################################
```

Please critique *any and all*

Comment: Would it be desirable to have rooms of different width within the same "column"? It looks a bit computer-generated with the equal width columns going down.

Comment: @maxb The width's are not always like this, it is random. By coincidence the rooms all have the same width in the example :)

Comment: @maxb I've added a better example output to avoid confusion. (It can happen because there is a minimal room space requirement, so it will stop splitting if the width or height is not big enough)

Comment: Ah, it looks better now!

Comment: Interesting question. Maybe it would be worth explaning the name "lu" and "rd".

Comment: lu = upper_left point, and rd == right_down point of the rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already nice-looking code. Some minor remarks

## upper and lower

on both `Leaf` and `Room`, things would become more clear if you defined a `left`, `right`, `up` and `down`

```
@property
def down(self):
    return self.rd.y

@property
def up(self):
    return self.lu.y

@property
def left(self):
    return self.lu.x

@property
def right(self):
    return self.rd.x
```

and then you can search and replace all mentions of `rd.x`, `rd.y`, `lu.x` and `lu.y`. Now I have to make the translation in my head every time.

## generators

`Room._get_border` and `Room._get_positions` return lists, while the code can be cleaner if they would return generators, using `itertools`' `product` and `chain`

```
def _get_positions(self):
    for y, x in itertools.product(
        range(self.left + 1, self.right), range(self.lower + 1, self.upper)
    ):
        yield Position(y, x)

def _get_border(self):

    left_wall = (Position(y, self.left) for y in range(self.upper, self.lower))
    right_wall = (Position(y, self.right) for y in range(self.upper, self.lower))
    upper_wall = (Position(self.upper, x) for x in range(self.left, self.right))
    lower_wall = (Position(self.lower, x) for x in range(self.left, self.right + 1))
    return itertools.chain(upper_wall, right_wall, lower_wall, left_wall)
```

## enumerable

It's good you use an enumerable for `Tile`, but then really use it. Don't convert to `.value` immediately like in Map.**init** and Map.generate. The translation only needs to be done in `__str__`. If later you want to add other properties to the tile, like resistance speed, or damage per turn, or whatever, by using the `.value` in the `Map`, you won't be able to.

so change `__str__` to:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "\n".join("".join(tile.value for tile in b) for b in self.board)
```

and remove the `.value` from the other places in the code

## Random seed

Allow for a random seed. This will help in testing, and later on if you want to generate the same game, you can easily do so.

All it needs, is a small change in `Map.generate`

```
def generate(self, random_seed=None):
    random.seed(random_seed)
    ...
```

## line split

If I need to split the arguments in a method call that is too long, I prefer to split immediately after the `(`, put the `)` on a separate line, and add a `,` after the last argument., like I adapted in `leaf_b`

```
            leaf_a = Leaf(leaf.lu,
                          Position(leaf.down, random_split),
                          leaf,
                          self.min_room_space)
            leaf_b = Leaf(
                Position(leaf.up, random_split + 1),
                leaf.rd,
                leaf,
                self.min_room_space,
            )
```

And since recently, I don't even worry about line splits any more. I use the [black](https://github.com/ambv/black) formatter, which is uncompromising, but has very sane settings.

## `_split_room`

The flows for a horizontal split and vertical split are completely separate, so I would make 2 separate functions out of it. Then you can drop the `Split` enumerable. You can pass functions variables, so `_split` can become:

```
def _split(self, leaf):
    if leaf.width / leaf.height >= self.split_threshold:
        split_func = self._split_room_horizontal
    elif leaf.height / leaf.width >= self.split_threshold:
        split_func = self._split_room_vertical
    else:
        split_func = random.choice(
            (self._split_room_vertical, self._split_room_horizontal)
        )
    return split_func(leaf)
```

## split success

at the moment, you convery whether a split was succesfull by leaving `leaf_a` and `leaf_b` to `None`. I'm always wary of using special return variables to signal the success of an operation. Another option here, would be to raise a `NotSplittable` Exception.

## generate

So at this moment, you initialize a `Map`, and only afterwards `generate()` the board. Why do you do that? This leaves room open for users of your code to forget to do the generation. I would do an initial generation. And if you want an option to generate a new board with the same settings, you can create a `regenerate` function, which returns a new map (with or without a new random seed)

## Tree

The Tree algorithm looks okay. I don't know what is the advantage of using `queue.Queue` instead of `collections.deque`.

The only thing I would change, would be to change the `leaves` property to into a tuple, and make it generate the leaves on the fly if they haven't been generated already.

```
@property
def leaves(self):
    if self._leaves is None:
        self._leaves = tuple(self._generate_leaves())
    return self._leaves
```

Then instead of using the second queue `leaves` in `_generate_leaves`, you could do `yield leave` instead of `leaves.put(leaf)` and drop the `self._leaves = list(leaves.queue)`

## properties

You make good use of properties, but sometimes you go overboard.

as they are implemented, `Leaf.children` and `Leaf.siblings` offer no advantages over using just an attribute

## keyword-only parameters

If you have a longer parameter list, especially with some who are used only seldomly, it can be clearer to mark them as [keyword-only](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/). For example:

```
class Map:
    def __init__(
        self, 
        width, 
        height, 
        *, 
        min_room_space=10, 
        split_threshold=1.25,
    ):
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing about code review, I am here to explain my hypothesis that this is not a good algorithm for "Dungon Map" as it can't generate random enough rooms

So from your algo

```
def _split(self, leaf):
    if leaf.width / leaf.height >= self.split_threshold:
        return self._split_room(leaf, Split.HORIZONTAL)
    elif leaf.height / leaf.width >= self.split_threshold:
        return self._split_room(leaf, Split.VERTICAL)
    else:
        return self._split_room(leaf, choice([Split.VERTICAL, Split.HORIZONTAL]))

def _split_room(self, leaf, direction):
    leaf_a = leaf_b = None
    if direction == Split.VERTICAL:
        if not leaf.height < self.min_room_space * 2:
            ...
    elif direction == Split.HORIZONTAL:
        if not leaf.width < self.min_room_space * 2:
            ...
    return leaf_a, leaf_b
```

The **split** will **stop** when:

- `leaf.height < self.min_room_space * 2` or `leaf.width < self.min_room_space * 2`
- And from `random_split = randint(leaf.lu.y + self.min_room_space, leaf.rd.y - self.min_room_space)` you've make sure that the room's width and heigh with at least `self.min_room_space` length
- `self.split_threshold` make sure width and height ratio, and whole space will be fully divided(no width/height longer than `min_room_space * 2`)
- and no extra space between rooms

So ultimately the whole space will be divided into rooms with width `self.min_room_space` to `self.min_room_space * 2` and same for height.

---

### So how will it looks like

Suppose I have `room 1` and `room 2` on the top now, looks like this and ready to add `room 3`, below `room 1`, on the top left of the whole space. And what's `room 3`'s width, **can only be the same as `room 1`**

[image]

Because no matter when `room 3` width larger or smaller than `room 1`, there is 
no possible to fill the "height gap" between `room 1` and `room 2`, as the height difference between is smaller than `min_room_space`

You might also find, these small rooms always try to be a "big box" together

So these are rooms with not to much difference in width and height, (the difference be smaller with smaller `min_room_space`) and try to be "big box" together all the time, I think they are well organized rooms

Comment: You are probably right that this may not be the best algo for it. Would you have any better suggestions?

Comment: simple improve, change the `min_room_space` to a range, instead of a single number.